# Game tree needs adjustment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've created the following game tree:

[image]

I want it to look like this and I'm stuck:

[image]

(Apologize in advance for the ugly drawing!)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}%{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm},bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

 \newcommand\term[2]{\node[below]at(#1){$#2$};}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,edge from parent/.style={draw,thin}]
  % Two node styles: solid and hollow
    \tikzstyle{solid node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black];
    \tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2];
  % Specify spacing for each level of the tree
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=34mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=11mm]
  % The Tree
  \node(0)[hollow node]{}
    child{node[solid node]{}edge from parent node[left]{Not buy}}
    child{node[solid node]at +(\tikzsiblingdistance,0){}
      child{node[hollow node]{}
        edge from parent node[left]{not buy}
      }
      child{node[hollow node]{}
        edge from parent node[right]{$P_r$}
      }
      edge from parent node[right]{$P_c$}
}
    child[sibling distance=5*\tikzsiblingdistance]{node[solid node]{}
      child{node[hollow node]{}
        edge from parent node[left]{not buy}
      }
      child{node[hollow node]{}
        edge from parent node[right]{$P_r$}
}
      edge from parent node[right,xshift=15]{$P_p$}
    };
  % information sets
  \draw[rounded corners=7]($(0-2)+(-.2,.25)$)rectangle($(0-3)+(.2,-.25)$);
  % specifying movers
  \draw[draw,<-,>=latex](0)--(32:8mm)node[right,inner sep=0]{Consumers decide whether or not to buy};
  \node at ($.5*(0-2)+.5*(0-3)$) {Remaining consumers decide to buy or not};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See, if the following MWE gives what you expected:

[image]
Figure is slightly changed in comparison to your sketch. If you not liked this, just change sibling distance accordingly and text write in one column.

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}% <-- new

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                   font = \footnotesize,
edge from parent/.style = {draw ,thin},
      SN/.style = {%solid node
                   circle, inner sep=1.2 ,fill=black},
      HN/.style = {%hollow node
                   circle, inner sep=1.2, draw=black,
                   },
 level distance = 15mm,
 level 1/.style = {sibling distance=42mm},
 level 2/.style = {sibling distance=21mm}
                    ]
%---
\linespread{0.8}
%-------
    \node (n0) [SN] {}
        child{ node (n1) [SN]  {}         
            child{node[HN]  {} 
                edge from parent node[left]{not buy}}
            child{node[HN]  {} 
                edge from parent node[right]{$P_r$}}
                edge from parent node[left]{$P_c$}
            }
        child{ node (n2) [SN]  {} 
            child{node[HN]  {} 
                edge from parent node[left]{not buy}}            
            child{node[HN]  {}
                edge from parent node[right]{$P_r$}}
                edge from parent node[right]{$P_r$}
            };
\node[draw, rounded corners=9pt,minimum height=7mm, align=center,
     fit=(n1) (n2),
     label={[align=center]center:Remaining consumers\\ decide to buy or not}] {};
\draw   (n0) -- node[above] {Not buy} (n1 |- n0) node[SN] {};
\draw[<-,shorten <=1pt]   
        (n0) -- + (1,1) node[right,align=left] {Consumers decide\\ 
                                                whether or not to buy};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Zarko, works. Only thing that is missing is the "Consumers decide whether or not to buy" text and arrow pointing on the beginning node.

Comment: uh, I forgot on it. now is added and also erased auxiliary label (needed in drawing for orientation where is node) . So, the MWE now should be complete :-)

Comment: Zarko, if I were to include a caption and a flatfoat to indicate source underneath the tree, where would I implement it? I've tried adding `\caption{Title}` just before `\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: You should include `tikzpicture` into `figure` environment:  `\begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\caption{...}\label{...}\end{figure}` (caption will appear below figure).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Forest version of your tree. One of the nice things about Forest is that it uses a bracket syntax which allows you to specify trees extremely concisely. And since it is TikZ-based, you can use the full power of TikZ in addition to Forest's range of features.

In this case, the tree itself is specified with this code:

```
  [, my pin=Consumers decide whether or not to buy
    [, edge label={node [midway, above] {Not buy}}, move me]
    [, my label=$P_c$, nudge=10pt
      [, my label=not buy]
      [, my label=$P_r$]
    ]
    [Remaining consumers decide to buy or not, tikz+={%
      \node [fit=() (!p) (!n), rounded corners=1.75ex, inner ysep=0pt, draw] {};
    }]
    [, my label=$P_p$, nudge=10pt
      [, my label=not buy]
      [, my label=$P_r$]
    ]
  ]
```

The `fit` library is used to draw the round-cornered rectangle around three nodes in the tree. These are specified using Forest's relative node names `!p` is the previous sibling and `!n` is the next sibling.

`my label` is a Forest style which sets the edge label to the left if the node is its parent's first child and to the right otherwise. `nudge` is used where the tree's branches slope too gently and the edges would clash with the labels otherwise. This is specified as a custom Forest option which is used by the `my label` style.

`my pin` uses Forest's `pin` option to add a label with an arrow. This is customised using TikZ's options for `pin`s.

`move me` is a Forest style which aligns a child vertically with its parent. This is done late in the tree construction to override the results of Forest's own packing algorithm and calculations.

[image: Forest tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}% version 2 or later required - tested with 2.0.3
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
}
\forestset{%
  declare dimen={nudge}{0pt},
  my pin/.style={%
    pin={[inner sep=0pt, pin distance=15pt]30:#1}
  },
  my label/.style={%
    delay={%
      if n=1{%
        edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, left, xshift=##1] {#1} }{nudge()}
      }{%
        edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, right, xshift=##1] {#1} }{nudge()}
      }
    }
  },
  move me/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      y/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{y("!u")}
    }
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  /tikz/every pin edge/.style={{Stealth[]}-},
  where level=1{%
    s sep+=50pt,
    delay={if content={}{solid node}{anchor=center,no edge}},
  }{hollow node},
  for tree={%
    l sep+=25pt,
    s sep+=5pt
  },
  [, my pin=Consumers decide whether or not to buy
    [, edge label={node [midway, above] {Not buy}}, move me]
    [, my label=$P_c$, nudge=10pt
      [, my label=not buy]
      [, my label=$P_r$]
    ]
    [Remaining consumers decide to buy or not, tikz+={%
      \node [fit=() (!p) (!n), rounded corners=1.75ex, inner ysep=0pt, draw] {};
    }]
    [, my label=$P_p$, nudge=10pt
      [, my label=not buy]
      [, my label=$P_r$]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: didn't know about the forest package. Thx!

Comment: cfr, I've posted the same question to Zarko: If I were to include a caption and a flatfoat to indicate source underneath the tree, where would I implement it? I've tried adding `\caption{Title}` just before `\end{tikzpic

Comment: @Saud What's a flatfoat? The usual way to add a caption is to do something like `\begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\caption{Caption text}\label{fig:thisfigurelabel}\end{figure}`. If you don't want the figure to float, you can use the `\captionof{}{}` command from either the `caption` or `capt-of` package instead.

Comment: Thx. I will give it a try. Flatfoat should of course have been floatfoot. I use floatfoot to give the figure a second "title" underneath. I usually write the source of the book or website I got the figure from.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package to draw game trees.
The `istgame` environment is almost the same as `tikzpicture` environment, which means that you can use any `tikzpicture` commands within `istgame` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\footnotesize]
% tree part
\xtdistance{15mm}{42mm}
\istroot(n0)
  \istb*<grow=west,level distance=21mm>{Not\ buy}[a]
  \endist
\istroot(n0)
  \istb{P_c}[al]
  \istb{P_r}[ar]
  \endist
\xtShowEndPoints[hollow node]
\xtdistance{15mm}{21mm}
\istroot(n1)(n0-1)
  \istb{not\ buy}[l]
  \istb{P_r}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(n2)(n0-2)
  \istb{not\ buy}[l]
  \istb{P_r}[r]
  \endist
% add some more
\xtInfosetO[solid,thin](n1)(n2){\makecell[c]{Remaining consumers\\[-1pt] decide to buy or not}}(10pt)
\draw [<-,>=latex,shorten <=2pt] (0,0) to [bend left] (32:8mm) node [right,inner sep=0] {\makecell[l]{Consumers decide\\ whether or not to buy}};
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```